# How do I do an outer join between all nested subqueries? (getting an error of 'OUTER' is not a valid input for this position)

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT AVG(a.score) AS Average1, AVG(b.score) AS Average2, AVG(c.score) AS Average3
FROM 
(SELECT subfactor.score, dateID, EmployeeID 
    FROM employeescore 
        LEFT JOIN subfactor 
        ON employeescore.SubFactorID = subfactor.SubFactorID 
            LEFT JOIN factor 
            ON subfactor.FactorID = factor.FactorID 
            WHERE DateID='Jan2015' AND employeescore.EmployeeID='1' AND subfactor.FactorID='A1')a 
OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT subfactor.score, DateID, EmployeeID 
    FROM employeescore 
        LEFT JOIN subfactor 
        ON employeescore.SubFactorID = subfactor.SubFactorID 
            LEFT JOIN factor 
            ON subfactor.FactorID = factor.FactorID 
                WHERE DateID='Feb2015' AND employeescore.EmployeeID='1' AND subfactor.FactorID='A1')b 
ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
OUTER JOIN
(SELECT subfactor.score, DateID, EmployeeID 
    FROM employeescore 
        LEFT JOIN subfactor 
        ON employeescore.SubFactorID = subfactor.SubFactorID 
            LEFT JOIN factor 
            ON subfactor.FactorID = factor.FactorID 
                WHERE DateID='Mar2015' AND employeescore.EmployeeID='1' AND subfactor.FactorID='A1')c 
ON b.EmployeeID = c.EmployeeID;
```

Basically I want to select the averages of the three scores and I want to display the output regardless if one of the joined sub queries doesn't have any records. But I keep getting an error of ('OUTER' is not a valid input for this position).
How can I repair?

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify whether you want an left, right or full outer join. A left outer join is the same as left join. Assuming this is what you want:

```
[...]
FROM (SELECT subfactor.score, dateID, EmployeeID 
      FROM employeescore 
      LEFT JOIN subfactor 
          ON employeescore.SubFactorID = subfactor.SubFactorID 
      LEFT JOIN factor 
          ON subfactor.FactorID = factor.FactorID 
      WHERE DateID='Jan2015' 
        AND employeescore.EmployeeID='1' 
        AND subfactor.FactorID='A1'
     ) a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT subfactor.score, DateID, EmployeeID 
           FROM employeescore 
           LEFT JOIN subfactor 
               ON employeescore.SubFactorID = subfactor.SubFactorID 
           LEFT JOIN factor 
               ON subfactor.FactorID = factor.FactorID 
           WHERE DateID='Feb2015' 
             AND employeescore.EmployeeID='1' 
             AND subfactor.FactorID='A1'
      )b 
          ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Lennart's answer explains why your query fails and how to fix it so it is syntactically correct.

About the additional problem that you *"want to display the output regardless if one of the joined sub queries doesn't have any rows"*, you could rewrite the query and simplify it:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(CASE WHEN es.DateID = 'Jan2015' THEN sf.score ELSE NULL END) AS Average1, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN es.DateID = 'Feb2015' THEN sf.score ELSE NULL END) AS Average2, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN es.DateID = 'Mar2015' THEN sf.score ELSE NULL END) AS Average3
FROM 
    employeescore AS es
  LEFT JOIN subfactor AS sf
    ON es.SubFactorID = sf.SubFactorID 
  LEFT JOIN factor AS f
    ON sf.FactorID = f.FactorID 
WHERE es.EmployeeID = '1' 
  AND sf.FactorID = 'A1' 
  AND es.DateID IN ('Jan2015', 'Feb2015', 'Mar2015') ;
```

Additional notes:

- the `WHERE subfactor.FactorID = 'A1'` condition means that the `LEFT JOIN subfactor` works essentially as `INNER JOIN subfactor`.
- the join to `factor` seems useless as no column of that table is used anywhere in the select list or the where condition. You could possibly remove the join for the query.

Answer (score -4):

Remove the keyword `OUTER`.  MySQL uses the ON/WHERE clause to decide between INNER and OUTER functionality.

There is another problem...  If Employee#1 was not there one of the months, the result will be the empty.  I suggest that you use a 4th subquery (first) to find all employes, then LEFT JOIN to each of the existing subqueries.

But then you may have another problem -- What happens with NULL in an AVG().  You *may* have to switch to `SUM(...) / COUNT(*)` to keep from the averages being strange.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "MySQL uses the ON/WHERE clause to decide between INNER and OUTER functionality" ?

Comment: FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.x=b.x -- the INNER is redundant.  FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.x=b.x WHERE b.id IS NULL -- the OUTER is redundant.  FROM a CROSS JOIN b (without ON or WHERE) -- CROSS is redundant.  FROM a,b is the same as FROM a JOIN b.  ON is sometimes turned into WHERE.  Do this with a query:  EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT ...; SHOW WARNINGS; -- You will see that MySQL adds/subtracts/rearranges JOIN-related stuff.  Even LEFT is removed _if_, because of NON NULL definitions, it is irrelevant.

Comment: I agree that the keywords `OUTER` and `INNER` is redundant, but saying that "MySQL uses the ON/WHERE clause to decide between INNER and OUTER functionality" is likely causing confusion for OP. Of the ANSI JOIN:s only CROSS JOIN is supposed to be without an ON clause (not sure why MySQL choosed to implement it the way they did)